# error installing python packages uisng pip

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pip

i removed python 3.10.5 and installed 3.11 and tried installing pandas package using pip
but i am getting an error like this:

```
C:\Users\Koushik Reddy>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.23.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (14.6 MB)
     ━━━╸━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.3/14.6 MB 468.8 kB/s eta 0:00:29
ERROR: Wheel 'numpy' located at C:\Users\.....\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-4o7ub4mx\numpy-1.23.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl is invalid.
```

can any one tell me what is causing this error?

Comment: Try updating pip using `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @BokiX already done that but still getting the same error

Comment: BTW, you didn't have to remove 3.10. Multiple Python versions can coexist just fine.

Comment: Try downloading some other numpy versions

Comment: can u tell me whats causing this cause this is too frustating for me i cant install any library

Comment: @BokiX how to do that?